# Why does Map.put() overwrite existing values in already existing key/value pairs?

Tags: java, spring, websocket, hashmap

A Map.put() overwrites existing values in itself, despite putting in a unique value.

I am initializing a singleton of an object "Game" in which I have a map of Rooms (and Players).

When I input new key/value pair into the roomsList like this:
roomsList.put(uniqueKey, new Room(uniqueKey, name)), the new key/value pair is added into the Map, but the rest of the pairs (each with a unique identifier) have their values overwritten as well.

I have tried putting in a new room already in my Spring Controller with Game.getRoomsList().put()
creating a separate object for client Messages so that instead of a Player message, 
- so the Controller's parameter is of object type NewRoomMessage
And even putting the key/value pairs directly in the private Game constructor...

The weird thing is, that with my Map playersList, everything works fine..

### Files in order of communication

**lobby.js**

This script sends name and generated roomId to the server endpoint /game/sessionId, where sessionId is the websocket identifier of a player, **roomId** is a newly generated ID and **name** is the user's input for new room name

```
function createRoom() {
    name = $('#inputRoomName').val();
    roomId = '_' + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);
    console.log(roomId);
    stompClient.send('/game/'+sessionId, {}, JSON.stringify({'message': name, 'roomId': roomId}));
}
```

This is my Spring controller which handles messages from Player for and is made for creating Rooms in game
**RoomsController**

```
@Controller
public class RoomsController {
    @MessageMapping("/game/{sessionId}")
    @SendTo("/topic/game/{sessionId}")  
    public RoomMessage createRoom(@DestinationVariable String sessionId, Player player) throws Exception {
        Game game = Game.getInstance();
        game.addRoom(player);
        return new RoomMessage("Room with the ID " + player.getRoomId() + " created");
    }
}
```

This is the Game Object which is a Singleton and with which my Spring server communicates

**Game.java**

package cz.vse.pavm07.bp.objects;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

```
@Controller
public class Game{
    private static Game game;
    /* 
    private static List<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();
    private static List<Player> playersToRemove = new ArrayList<Player>(); 
    */
    private static Map<String, Player> playersList = new HashMap<String, Player>();
    private static Map<String, Player> playersToRemove = new HashMap<String, Player>();
    private static Map<String, Room> roomsList = new HashMap<String, Room>();
    private static Map<String, Room> roomsToRemove = new HashMap<String, Room>();

// LAZY SINGLETON GAME
    private Game() {}

    public static Game getInstance() throws Exception{
        if(game == null) {
            game = new Game();
        }
        return game;
    }
    /* This is the method I have issues with, it somehow overwrites already existing values in my Map of Rooms */
    /* ROOMS LIST */

    public static boolean addRoom(Player player) {
        if (!roomsList.containsKey(player.getRoomId())) {
            roomsList.put(player.getRoomId(), new Room(player.getRoomId(), player.getMessage()));
            return true;
        }       
        return false;
    }


    /*  PLAYERS LISTS */
    /*  Method adds new player to the playersList and it works right */ 
    public static boolean addPlayer(String sessionId, String name) {
        if (playersList.containsKey(sessionId)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            playersList.put(sessionId, new Player(sessionId, name));
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Room constructor
**Room.java**

```
public Room (String ID, String name) {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.name = name;
    }
```

**Example output:**

```
NEW ROOM IS ADDED
I am printing out the keyset of my roomsList, and then for each room its key, its ID and its Name
[_y46r22hdu]
The Key of the Room is_y46r22hdu, The ID is _y46r22hdu and the Name of the room isRoom1

NEW ROOM IS ADDED
I am printing out the keyset of my roomsList, and then for each room its key, its ID and its Name
[_jxltglk5z, _y46r22hdu]
The Key of the Room is_jxltglk5z, The ID is _jxltglk5z and the Name of the room isRoom2
The Key of the Room is_y46r22hdu, The ID is _jxltglk5z and the Name of the room isRoom2
```

I expect the Map to add a new Object without overwriting the already existing key/value pairs...

The link to this project's repository is here: https://github.com/MartinPavelka/chaser-server

Comment: All your fields are static. So there is a single ID and a single name, shared by all Room instances. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The error is in your [`Room`](https://github.com/MartinPavelka/chaser-server/blob/master/src/main/java/cz/vse/pavm07/bp/objects/Room.java) class. Both `name` and `ID` are static fields, whereas you're *expecting* each instance to have a separate pair of fields.

So this:

```
private static String name;
private static String ID;
```

should be

```
private String name;
private String id; // Name changed to follow conventions
```

I'd personally make them `final` as well, to make it clear they don't change over the course of the lifetime of the object:

```
private final String name;
private final String id;
```

You'll want to change some of your static methods to be instance methods, too... and look at the rest of your fields. Basically you need take care about what aspects of state are intended to be type-wide (static), and what aspects are meant to be per-instance. (You should look at the same issues for `Game`, as well. Fundamentally static fields are usually pretty rare in an application. When you end up with almost all your fields static - as per your project at the moment - that suggests you need to look at the design again.)

Comment: As dear Boris the Spider would tell, make it all final. :-) @JonSkeet